# Bootstrap 3 display block mobile only

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible in bootstrap 3 to set an element to be block for mobile (xs) and inline for all other screen sizes?

For example:

```
<span class="display-block-xs">content here</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can use it this way

```
<div class="visible-xs-block  visible-sm-inline-block visible-md-inline-block visible-lg-inline-block">fadi</div>
```

this div will become block on mobile but inline block on others devices screen

Answer (score 1):

I made some research it seem that on bootstrap 3 you have already:

```
.visible-xs-inline
```

and

```
.visible-xs-inline-block
```

and you can use:

```
.hidden-xs
```

for inline elements safely. Hope it can help you.